# How to access innerText of HTML tag inside a <span> tag

Tags: html, excel, vba

I would like to get some text from a web page containing this HTML.

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="en">
    <span class="hps">mothers</span>
    <span class="hps">love</span>
</span>
```

I'm trying to use:

```
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText
Set objResult = html.getelementbyid("result_box")
For Each span In objResult
Set objspan = objResult.getelementsbytagname("span")(0).innerText
Range(1, 2) = objspan
Next
```

I'm trying to get the text **mothers love** in Cell(1,2).

Comment: so what output you get now?

Comment: I got _Object required_ error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not excel vba master but logically your code should be like this

```
For Each span In objResult
Set objspan = objspan + objResult.getelementsbytagname("span")(0).innerText 

Next

Range(1, 2) = objspan
```

You first need to build string and then assign to cell outside loop. Hope you understand the logic.